# Select only the lowest values with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, c#-4.0

Hi
I got the following linq for ordering my input after lowest value.
But i would like it to only output the lowest values.

```
var sortedDict = (from entry in x where entry.Value > 0 orderby entry.Value ascending select entry);
```

Now if it gets the following input.

```
3  4  2  6  2
```

This would be my output

```
2  2  3  4  6
```

What do I need to change in my linq so I only get this output

```
2  2
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```
int min = x.Min(entry => entry.Value);
var lowestValues = x.Where(entry => entry.Value == min);
```

Note that I've explicitly split these up, as if you use `Where(entry => entry.Value == x.Min(y => y.Value))` it will look for the minimum on *every iteration*. On the other hand, that's true of LINQ to Objects - but in LINQ to SQL it would probably be *better* to do it all in one query, and let the database sort it out.

Comment: Will this be faster than KJN's answer? Will his answer cause Min() to be recalculated for each entry inside the data list, or will the compiler do some caching of this value. I doubt it, but I would like to get it confirmed one way or the other.

Comment: @Øyvind Bråthen: If you're using LINQ to Objects, then yes - Min() will be recalculated for each entry in the list.

Answer (score 10):

You could try something like this:

```
data.Where (d => d == data.Min())
```

Note this is not necessarily the fastest way to do this.

Comment: If you cache data.Min() in a variable you can take this from O(n^2) to O(n). I'm making an assumption about the implementation of these linq functions and the C# compiler.

Answer (score 6):

First, find the lowest value:

```
var min = (from entry in x where entry.Value > 0 select entry).Min();
```

Then, select items:

```
var sortedDict = from entry in x where entry.Value == min select entry
```

Sorting is not needed for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for being the only one to rember checking for numbers above 0 :-)